# Customize the termination signal sent to subprocess that exceeds limits set by `resource.setrlimit()` in Python

Tags: python, linux, unix, process, signals

I am writing an online judge for a competitive programming website and I want to detect if a program has exceeded the specified memory limits that results in the `MLE` (Memory Limit Exceeded) verdict.

I am using a python script to run the program and applying limits using `resource.setrlimit()` like this

```py
def apply_constraints(time_limit, mem_limit, stack_size):
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (time_limit, time_limit))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (mem_limit, mem_limit))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (stack_size, stack_size))
```

and this is the function to execute commands

```py
def execute_submission(
    command, time_limit, mem_limit, stack_size, input_file, output_file
):
    start_time = time.time()

    with open(input_file, "r") as infile, open(output_file, "w") as outfile:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command,    
            stdin=infile,
            stdout=outfile,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            preexec_fn=apply_constraints(time_limit, mem_limit, stack_size),
        )
        process.communicate()

        mem_used = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN).ru_maxrss
        end_time = time.time()
        return process.returncode, end_time - start_time, mem_used
```

Now, the problem is that if a program tries to allocate more memory than it is allowed to, it gets sent with a `SIGSEGV` signal and exits with a return code of `-11` but the problem is that if the program being judged tries to de-reference a `nullptr` like this:

```cpp
int* p = nullptr;
*p = 3;
```

It also terminates with a `SIGSEGV` signal but for the online judge, this should be a *run-time error* rather than an `MLE` so I am looking for a way to differentiate between the two.

You might notice that I am also measuring the memory used by the program so I first thought about using that as an indicator for if it was really an `MLE` but if you try to allocate a large chunk of memory which is out of the limits, that memory isn't allocated to your program because of the set limits so it doesn't get counted in the memory used and therefore, the memory usage registers no where near the memory limit even though trying to allocate more memory was the cause of it's termination i.e, an `MLE`. Meaning, this approach would also fail at trying to differentiate between these two cases of termination.

Comment: Unrelated: `preexec_fn=apply_constraints(time_limit, mem_limit, stack_size)` executes `apply_constraints(time_limit, mem_limit, stack_size)` in the parent, finds that it returns `None`, then passes that `None` as the value of `preexec_fn`. You need to pass an actual function, perhaps creating one with `lambda`.

Comment: But the limits are being applied. Meaning, the function is executing.

Comment: It's executing, *in the parent*. That means the parent is applying those limits to itself, then the child inherits the limits, instead of the child applying the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. You can't customize the signals sent for exceeding an rlimit, but also, the memory rlimits largely aren't enforced with signals. A program that tries to grow its stack beyond the rlimit gets a SIGSEGV, but quoting the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html):

> RLIMIT_AS
> This is the maximum size of total available memory of the process, in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() and mmap() functions shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM]. In addition, the automatic stack growth fails with the effects outlined above.

A program that tries to `malloc` beyond the rlimit just gets a null pointer and errno set to ENOMEM. If the program tries to use the `malloc` return value without checking it, *then* the program gets a SIGSEGV simply because it's dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Comment: But some other online judges are able to make this distinction. What alternative approach would you suggest?

Comment: They might be using `LD_PRELOAD` to replace `malloc`, or something like that. I don't know how those judges are implemented.